# Numba nopython mode cannot accept 2-D boolean indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numba

I am trying to accelerate code with `numba`(currently I am using `numba 0.45.1`) and come across a problem with boolean indexing. The code is as follows:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

n_max = 1000

n_arr = np.hstack((np.arange(1,3),
                   np.arange(3,n_max, 3)
                   ))

@njit
def func(arr):
    idx =  np.arange(arr[-1]).reshape((-1,1)) < arr -2
    result = np.zeros(idx.shape)
    result[idx] = 10.1
    return result

new_arr = func(n_arr)
```

As soon as I run the code, I get the following message

```
TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function setitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 2d, C), array(bool, 2d, C), float64)
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    TypeError: unsupported array index type array(bool, 2d, C) in [array(bool, 2d, C)]
    raised from C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\arraydecl.py:71
In definition 9:
    TypeError: unsupported array index type array(bool, 2d, C) in [array(bool, 2d, C)]
    raised from C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\arraydecl.py:71
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of setitem at C:/Users/User/Desktop/all python file/5.5.5/numba index broadcasting2.py (29)
```

Note that the `(29)` at the last line corresponds to line 29, which is `result[idx] = 10.1`, the line I tried to assign value to result whose index is `idx`, a 2-D boolean index.

---

I'd like to explain that including that statement `result[idx] = 10.1` inside `@njit` is a must. As much as I want to exclude this statement in `@njit`, I can't, because this line sits right in the middle of a code I am working on.

If I insist to include the assignment statement `result[idx] = 10.1` inside `@njit`, what exactly needs to be changed in order to make it work? If possible I'd like to see some code example that involves 2-D boolean index inside `@njit` that can be run.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numba does not currently support fancy indexing with a 2D array. See:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#array-access

However you can get equivalent behavior by re-writing your function with for-loops explicitly rather than relying on broadcasting:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

n_max = 1000

n_arr = np.hstack((np.arange(1,3),
                   np.arange(3,n_max, 3)
                   ))

def func(arr):
    idx =  np.arange(arr[-1]).reshape((-1,1)) < arr -2
    result = np.zeros(idx.shape)
    result[idx] = 10.1
    return result

@njit
def func2(arr):
    M = arr[-1]
    N = arr.shape[0]
    result = np.zeros((M, N))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            if i < arr[j] - 2:
                result[i, j] = 10.1

    return result

new_arr = func(n_arr)
new_arr2 = func2(n_arr)
print(np.allclose(new_arr, new_arr2))  # True
```

On my machine, and with the example inputs you provided, `func2` is about 3.5x faster than `func`.

Comment: Interesting. Seeing that in this case broadcasting is slower than a for-loop in `@njit`,  I wonder if this holds True for most of the large data operations? I am asking this because although I am only doing broadcasting in `numpy` array in this example, in future, I will do broadcasting in `tensorflow` setting, so it will be really great to know the answer to this question.